# How to export a line of text that has a specifc word to another text file?

Tags: text-processing, macos

I have a large list of text and, to make it easier to sort through, I would like to be able to export lines that feature certain words to another text file.

Here is an example of the text:

```
- JOCKEY: D Tudhope riding Dynamic Force in the 1.45 at Ayr
- TRAINER: A W Carroll training Be Fair in the 1.55 at Lingfield Park
- TRAINER: M L W Bell training The Vegas Raider in the 1.55 at Lingfield Park
- JOCKEY: Oisin Murphy riding The Vegas Raider in the 1.55 at Lingfield Park
- JOCKEY: W Buick riding Crestwood in the 1.55 at Lingfield Park
- TRAINER: P F Nicholls training Chez Hans in the 2.05 at Newton Abbot
- JOCKEY: Callum Rodriguez riding Gigiʼs Beach in the 2.15 at Ayr
```

How can I export only the lines that say "Lingfield Park" to another text file?

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple `grep` + redirection:

```
$ grep '\bLingfield Park\b' FILE > ANOTHER_FILE
$ cat ANOTHER_FILE
- TRAINER: A W Carroll training Be Fair in the 1.55 at Lingfield Park
- TRAINER: M L W Bell training The Vegas Raider in the 1.55 at Lingfield Park
- JOCKEY: Oisin Murphy riding The Vegas Raider in the 1.55 at Lingfield Park
- JOCKEY: W Buick riding Crestwood in the 1.55 at Lingfield Park
```

Comment: If you like this answer please mark it as solved to let other users
know your problem is solved. Also see [What should I do when someone
answers my
question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: If multiple patterns must be matched, they can be put in a file named `patterns.txt` and then `grep -f patterns.txt FILE > ANOTHER_FILE` can be run ([documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Matching-Control.html#index-patterns-from-file)).

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: yes, it's also possible